# Open addresses in google maps instead of apple maps

Tags: iphone, maps, google-maps

Street addresses in Messages, Calendar, etc appear as links to click.  But when I tap on these links, they open in Apple maps.  I prefer to use google maps (or citymapper, where available).

How can I configure my iPhone so that it's opening addresses in the maps application of my preference?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, you can't (unless you jailbreak your iPhone).
Anyway, from iOS 8, you are allowed to use your preferred navigator, once Maps has been opened:

1. Open an address (it will open with Apple Maps by default).
2. Tap the "car" button, as you do to get directions.
3. Tap the "share" button, then tap "Transport apps".
4. Choose the app navigator you prefer, among the installed ones (i.e., Google Maps). You will be redirected to the one you chose.

It's not as changing the default, but it's surely easier than typing an address manually in your preferred app.

Comment: Hi!  Thanks but that's a lot of tapping .. it's really impossible to change the default maps app???  But that seems like such a basic and obvious feature..

Comment: As far as I know, it is for customers, maybe not for Apple board director :-)

Comment: Things like this cause people to hate apple. Sorry apple you’re not doing yourself any favors on this. Let people decide their app of choice

Answer (score 2):

You cannot in IOS > 8. However if you are still on 8 [there is a way](https://www.imobie.com/support/how-to-make-google-maps-default-on-iphone.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no default selection of Google maps via FB app. I dont know if Apple doesnt allow it or FB doesnt care to add this functionality in Apple apps.

The simplest way in latest iOS update(14.4) to do this is click on the 3 dots ... at the end of a place/address in FB, then you will get options. Select "directions" from that list and you will get a popup to choose directions in Apple Maps or Google Maps. You choose Google Maps!

Answer (score -1):

Copy address, open Google Maps, paste address.

Comment: You can't copy an address from Apple Calendar events in iOS; it copies as a link to Apple Maps.